# How to pass multiple data back from child to parent component in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Currently, I am using angular 4 for my school project. I have an array, each item is a child component which can be updated and deleted, which means I should know the index and the data.

parent.ts:

```
updOne(i:number,stc:string):void{
    this.myarray[i]=stc
}
delete(edu:string):void{
    this.myarray=this.myarray.filter(x=>x!==edu)
}
```

parent.html:

```
<child-com [edu]=x [num]=i (updstr)="updOne($event)" (delstr)="delete($event)"></child-com>
```

child-com.ts:

```
@Input() edu:string
@Input() num:number
@Output() updstr: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>()
@Output() delstr: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>()

//some other code here

save():void{
    this.updstr.emit(this.edu)
    this.updating=false
}
del():void{
    this.delstr.emit(this.edu)
}
```

delete works well, without a doubt. The problem is updating. Actually, using *ngFor, trackBy, and printing it all manually, this problem can be solved. But I wanna try using child component, as in React. When I play around with react, I can just use javascript closure, i.e. myfunc.bind(this,i,stc).

I've tried using bind here, no results

code when using bind:
parent.ts:

```
@Output() updstr: EventEmitter<number,string> = new EventEmitter<number,string>()
```

parent.html:

```
//I've tried some order
//this,i,$event
//$event,this,i
<child-com [edu]=x (updstr)="updOne.bind(this,$event,i)" (delstr)="delete($event)"></child-com>
```

And generics in typescript doesn't allow multiple data, so I cant emit more than one data

So my question is, how can I pass some data at once from child to parent, using emit or bind?

Comment: Simply send an Object containing your data : 
`{ testNumber : 1, testString: 'test' }`
. Using an interface is cleaner than an anonymous object though.
See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child : the `@Output` example is with a boolean but can be of any type.

Comment: Oh, thank you, now it works. But it means the only argument passed for function can only be $event?

Comment: Yes, it's an EventEmitter of your typed Object. That Object can be everything, an array, an Object containing objects, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Alex, using an object can substitute multiple data passing. Just to make sure that the data is correct, an interface is used, kind of like this

```
export interface Interview{
    num:number
    payload:{
        dt:string
        seeker:string
    }
}
```

and used it like

```
@Output() updstr: EventEmitter<Interview> = new EventEmitter<Interview>()
```